# Why isn't TF2's Dataset.map behaving like a normal for-loop traversal?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have a dataset of song lyrics:

```py
lyrics = [
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    ]

lyrics_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(lyrics)
```

Calling `.numpy()` on each element inside a for loop works fine...

```py
for song in lyrics_dataset:
    print(song.numpy())
```

... But doing the same through `.map()` doesn't work:

```py
transformation = lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x.numpy())
transformed_dataset = lyrics_dataset.map(transformation)
```

(giving `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`)

Why?

Comment: Hi, what structure of dataset do you want to get after the mapping?

Comment: I would like `transformed_dataset` to have the same structure as `lyrics_dataset`. More specifically I would like to process each element of `lyrics_dataset` with a function that internally calls `.numpy()` on its input, and returns a string.

Comment: You can't convert it to numpy inside of the mapping because it is considered as a regular tensor. when you iterate on the dataset it creates "eagerTensors" that can be converted to numpy.
it's like map_fn in tensorflow1.X.
but also you can convert your numpy code to tensorflow with a better performance.

Comment: Thank you @Tolik, that also makes sense with what I could find by researching a bit more. If you post this as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert it to numpy inside of the mapping because it is considered as a regular tensor. when you iterate on the dataset it creates "eagerTensors" that can be converted to numpy. it's like map_fn in tensorflow1.X. but also you can convert your numpy code to tensorflow with a better performance.